# Create a new MySQL Database from existing db with up to 10000 rows of data from each table

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a database with some data not all. I don't need 1M+ records to do what I need so I am okay with only 10000 rows.

I figured I can use a stored procedure to loop through all the table and manually create each table and insert only 10000 rows.

I created a stored procedure like this

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`10.%` PROCEDURE `createNewDatabase`(in db_name varchar(100), in new_db_name varchar(100))
BEGIN

    DECLARE finish INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE tbl VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE cur_tables CURSOR FOR SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = db_name AND TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE';

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finish = 1;

    OPEN cur_tables;

    my_loop: LOOP

        FETCH cur_tables INTO tbl;

            IF finish = 1 THEN
                LEAVE my_loop;
            END IF;

            SET @str = CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `', new_db_name, '`.`' , tbl , '`; CREATE TABLE `', new_db_name, '`.`' , tbl , '` LIKE `', db_name , '`.`', tbl,'`; INSERT INTO `', new_db_name , '`.`' , tbl, '` SELECT * FROM `', db_name ,'`.`', tbl , '` LIMIT 10000;');


            PREPARE stmt FROM @str;
            EXECUTE stmt;

            DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

        END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur_tables;

END
```

Then I called it like this
CALL `createNewDatabase`('baseTable', 'newTable');

But I run the procedure I get the following error

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE `newTable`.`account_addresses` LIKE `baseTable`.`account_addres' at line 1
```

if I added the following 2 lines after just before the prepare statement

```
SELECT @str;
LEAVE my_loop;
```

I get the following queries which works if I executed them manually

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `newTable`.`account_addresses`; 
CREATE TABLE `newTable`.`account_addresses` LIKE `baseTable`.`account_addresses`; 
INSERT INTO `newTable`.`account_addresses` SELECT * FROM `newTable`.`account_addresses` LIMIT 10000;

CREATE TABLE `newTable`.`account_addresses` LIKE `baseTable`.`account_addresses`; INSERT INTO `newTable`.`account_addresses` SELECT * FROM `baseTable`.`account_addresses` LIMIT 10000;
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why it is erroring?

Answer (score 0):

Quote from mysql's documentation on [PREPARE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/prepare.html):

> The text must represent a single statement, not multiple statements.

You are trying to execute a drop table and a create table statement, insert records in 1 prepared statement and this is not allowed. Have 3 separate prepared statement for the 3 commands.